# Linux Mint "OEM temporary account" convertible to my permanent user account?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

In my eagerness to switch from windoze, i installed all my sw and data when i first installed linux and now i realize it's all under the OEM temporary account. I'm afraid when I reboot all my data will be wiped.

Any way to convert this OEM temporary account into a normal account in Linux Mint? Thanks so much!!

Comment: What's the "OEM temporary account"?

Comment: I learned after the fact that the OEM temporary account is for hardware sellers to setup the system to install in a custom way so upon first boot at end user it gets setup a certain way perhaps with added drivers and so on.

Comment: I remember reading about OEM images, but never had a desire to try them

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Mint for years and I only know the "mint" account when you run live (directly off the cd/usb/iso) and I believe the installer asks you to provide a username when installing.

Did you install Mint yet?

---

If you're still running **live** from the iso, you can install programs & copy files to your home, but they will be lost on a reboot - unless you're using a **persistent** file or partition.

You're free to copy your home folder ( normally `/home/mint` but verify with `cd ~` or just `cd` and `pwd` or `echo $HOME`) to a permanent storage; that would save most of the config files - a big .tar.gz archive file would work. Then you can extract it later to your "real" installed home, and just re-install whatever programs you want.

---

If you really installed Mint already, and you want to switch to a new user, you could just make a new user (use GUI - `users-admin` in a terminal, or run `adduser`) then copy the old home files to the new user's home, change the owner & group to match the new user, and most *should* be ok.

In case there's any direct references to the old /home/olduser folder, then change them to the new /home/newuser folder.